# qTip: prevent hiding the tip two times successively

Tags: javascript, qtip

First of all sorry guys for posting the question here. The [support forum](http://craigsworks.com/projects/forums/newthread.php?fid=10) seems to be almost dead.

So I've run into a bug in the qtip plugin or my code. When I call `.qtip('hide')` twice or more times consecutively, the tooltip will hide and never show again when calling `.qtip('show')`.

The way to reproduce:

`el.qtip('hide');el.qtip('hide');el.qtip('show');  \\ -> bug, the tip is not shown` 
`el.qtip('hide');el.qtip('hide');el.qtip('hide');el.qtip('show');  \\ -> bug, same`

Consecutive `show` works good...

`el.qtip('show');el.qtip('show');el.qtip('hide');el.qtip('show');  \\ -> pass`

Non - consecutive `hide` also works good:

`el.qtip('hide');el.qtip('show');el.qtip('hide');el.qtip('show');  \\ -> pass`

The question is:

How to make things work? The qTip api does not give me a way to find if the tip is hidden or shown. How can I know that? I can check if the qTip is hidden not to hide it twice.

Possible source of problem:

The qtip causing errors is constructed in a rather tricky way:

```
qtip({
            content: text,
            position: {
                corner: {
                    target: 'rightMiddle',
                    tooltip: 'leftMiddle'
                }
            },
            style: {
                tip: {
                     corner: 'leftMiddle',
                },
                border: {
                    radius: 11,
                    width: 4
                },
                name: 'red'
            },
            show: {
                delay:0,
                ready: true,
                fixed:true,
                when: { target: false, event:false },
                effect: function() {//.stop(true, true)
                    $(this).effect("drop", { direction: "down", mode: "show" }, 240)
                }
            },
            hide: {
                delay:0,
                fixed:true,
                when: { target: false, event:false },
                effect: function() {//.stop(true, true)
                    $(this).effect("drop", { direction: "down", mode: "hide" }, 240)
                }
            }
        })
```

---

To test this, you can go to www.buxdial.com/oldo/register.php, type anything in the captcha field, go to debugger and run the tests, replacing `el` with `code.TIP`

Comment: I was using qTip to begin with, but I changed. Now, I use TooptisY for tooltips (This is excellent). And I use simpleModal (created by one of us here) for larger content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have just one instance of a qtip on your page you can check to see if the qtip is currently showing by searching for the `qtip-active` class. Here is an example using jquery on how to check:

```
if($('div.qtip-active').length) {
   alert("qtip is currently showing");
}
else {
   alert("qtip is hidden");
}
```